# Make a new table with rearranged pieces in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am converting some SAS code into R and am stuck on a portion to reshape the final data output into a new format. I have a data frame, df, that looks like this:

```
 State  AREA Year species ncount_ip   est.ip     se.ip  est.tib    se.tib
1    CT 12593 2015    ABDU        56 1349.250  943.2464  4497.50 2871.4829
2    CT 12593 2015    GADW        56  224.875  224.3744  6746.25 6290.3472
3    CT 12593 2015    COME        56    0.000    0.0000     0.00    0.0000
4    VT 12593 2015    ABDU        56 8545.250 1756.8546 19114.38 5443.0618
5    VT 12593 2015    COME        56  674.625  498.0543  1349.25  996.1086
6    VT 12593 2015    GADW        56  224.875  224.3744   449.75  448.7489
```

That I want to put in a format like this (final):

```
Species Type    Year    VTest     VTse      CTest       CTse
GADW    Pop     2015    449.75    448.7489  6746.25     6290.3472
GADW    Pairs   2015    224.875   224.3744  224.875     224.3744
ABDU    Pop     2015    19114.38  5443.0618 4497.50     2871.4829
ABDU    Pairs   2015    8545.250  1756.8546 1349.250    943.2464
COME    Pop     2015    1349.25   996.1086  0.00        0.00
COME    Pairs   2015    674.625   498.0543  0.00        0.00
```

Basically, I need to take from df the estimate (est) and standard error (se) of pop. (.tib) and pairs (.ip) for each state (only 2 given in example but about 10 in actual dataset) to form 2 rows for each species with 2 columns for each state to create final.

I started by trying package reshape and melting but don't quite get what I need. I think renaming by state after melting might work, but can't code that up appropriately. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I'm not sure there exists a predefined function for what you want but it seems fairly straightforward: subset for species (and type) (e.g. using `sub = df[df$species == ABDU,]` etc.), calculate estimate (i guess this is `mean`) and standard error for each subset and bind that together. Why don't you show us your efforts in code?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. No summarizing is needed. All the numbers are there they just need to be rearranged. I edited the code so the numbers for species ABDU are in the correct location in each data frame.

Comment: Are all the Year values 2015?  What if there are multiple Year values within a State or species group?

Comment: Could you explain how you get, for example, the first row in your output.. those values are nowhere in your input..

Comment: I was using the output only as an example, but I have now changed it to reflect where the numbers in df are supposed to go in the final output.

Comment: For this task all the years are the same. Shouldn't have to do multiple years at all, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your `df`, and using the `reshape2` package, first melt the dataframe, preserving the first 5 columns:

```
> library(reshape2)
> melted <- melt(df, id.vars=1:5)
> head(melted)
  State  AREA Year species ncount_ip variable    value
1    CT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 1349.250
2    CT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875
3    CT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip    0.000
4    VT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 8545.250
5    VT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip  674.625
6    VT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875
```

Use `colsplit` to pull out the statistic and type identifiers from the new `variable` column (old headers), and add these columns to dataframe:

```
> melted <- cbind(melted,
+ colsplit(melted$variable, "\\.", c('stat','type')))
> head(melted)
  State  AREA Year species ncount_ip variable    value stat type
1    CT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 1349.250  est   ip
2    CT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875  est   ip
3    CT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip    0.000  est   ip
4    VT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 8545.250  est   ip
5    VT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip  674.625  est   ip
6    VT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875  est   ip
```

Combine `State` and `stat` to achieve your desired labels, and replace strings in `type`:

```
> melted$state_stat <- paste(melted$State, melted$stat, sep ="_")
> melted$type <- gsub("tib", "Pop", melted$type)
> melted$type <- gsub("ip", "Pairs", melted$type)
> head(melted)
  State  AREA Year species ncount_ip variable    value stat  type state_stat
1    CT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 1349.250  est Pairs     CT_est
2    CT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875  est Pairs     CT_est
3    CT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip    0.000  est Pairs     CT_est
4    VT 12593 2015    ABDU        56   est.ip 8545.250  est Pairs     VT_est
5    VT 12593 2015    COME        56   est.ip  674.625  est Pairs     VT_est
6    VT 12593 2015    GADW        56   est.ip  224.875  est Pairs     VT_est
```

Recast the dataframe, using new `state_stat` column for columns:

```
> final <- dcast(melted, Year+species+type~state_stat, value.var="value")
> final
  Year species  type   CT_est     CT_se    VT_est     VT_se
1 2015    ABDU Pairs 1349.250  943.2464  8545.250 1756.8546
2 2015    ABDU   Pop 4497.500 2871.4829 19114.380 5443.0618
3 2015    COME Pairs    0.000    0.0000   674.625  498.0543
4 2015    COME   Pop    0.000    0.0000  1349.250  996.1086
5 2015    GADW Pairs  224.875  224.3744   224.875  224.3744
6 2015    GADW   Pop 6746.250 6290.3472   449.750  448.7489
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a note to others, make sure to use the reshape2 package, not reshape. Doesn't seem to work with the earlier version.